# Sync selected nav jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following kinda working with the exception that I'm unable to have the selected Nav highlighted (red) when you using the next & prev buttons. I've also opted not to use an id on the panels as there might be more added or removed. And is there a more efficient way to script this.

```js
$(function($) {
  $(document).on('click', ".slidenav", function() {

    $("span.slidenav").on('click', function() {
      $(".panel").removeClass("active");
      var newPanel = $(this).index();
      $(".panel").eq(newPanel).addClass("active");

      $("span.slidenav").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    });

  });

});

$(document).on('click', "#next", function() {

  if ($('.active').next('.panel').length) {
    $('.active').removeClass('active')
      .next('.panel')
      .addClass('active');
  }

});

$(document).on('click', "#prev", function() {
  if ($('.active').prev('.panel').length) {
    $('.active').removeClass('active')
      .prev('.panel,.slidenav')
      .addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.panel:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ddd;
}
.panel:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ccc;
}
.panel:nth-child(3) {
  background: #bbb;
}
.panel:nth-child(4) {
  background: #aaa;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <span class="slidenav selected">Panel 1</span>
    <span class="slidenav">Panel 2</span>
    <span class="slidenav">Panel 3</span>
    <span class="slidenav">Panel 4</span>
</nav>
<hr>
<div id="prev">Prev</div>
<div id="next">Next</div>
<hr>
<div class="panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel active">
    Panel 1
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    Panel 2
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    Panel 3
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    Panel 4
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYpopb) for the whole thing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do the same that you're doing with the `.active` class on the `.panel` elements, but with the `.selected` class on the `.slidenav` elements.

**Update:** There was also something wrong with your first event binding: On each click event on a `.slidenav` element, you bound to the click event again and again.

```js
$(function($) {

  $("span.slidenav").on('click', function() {
    $(".panel").removeClass("active");
    var newPanel = $(this).index();
    $(".panel").eq(newPanel).addClass("active");

    $("span.slidenav").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', "#next", function() {
    if ($('.active').next('.panel').length) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
                    .next('.panel')
                    .addClass('active');
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected')
                    .next('.slidenav')
                    .addClass('selected');
    }

  });

  $(document).on('click', "#prev", function() {
    if ($('.active').prev('.panel').length) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active')
                    .prev('.panel')
                    .addClass('active');
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected')
                    .prev('.slidenav')
                    .addClass('selected');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.panel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.panel:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ddd;
}
.panel:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ccc;
}
.panel:nth-child(3) {
  background: #bbb;
}
.panel:nth-child(4) {
  background: #aaa;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <span class="slidenav selected">Panel 1</span>
    <span class="slidenav">Panel 2</span>
    <span class="slidenav">Panel 3</span>
    <span class="slidenav">Panel 4</span>
</nav>
<hr>
<div id="prev">Prev</div>
<div id="next">Next</div>
<hr>
<div class="panel-wrap">
    <div class="panel active">
    Panel 1
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    Panel 2
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    Panel 3
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    Panel 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did that as well, guess must have missed something. Awesome @Connum thanks for that.

Comment: Updated my answer again due to some other minor problems with your code (re-binding of the click event on every click and your closure not wrapping all of the code).

Comment: Yep noticed that, Thanks, was wondering why that was happening.